# Why can't I get ref if the target is an AsyncComponent in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

If i'm importing component with `import SearchBarPopper from './xxx'`:

```
import SearchBarPopper from './search-bar-popper';
export default {
  components: {
    SearchBarPopper,
  },
};
```

Define ref name in template:

```
<search-bar-popper ref="popper" />
```

Then call its function when some other component triggers `@click`:

```
methods: {
  onClick(index) {
    console.log(this.$refs.popper);
    if (this.$refs.popper) {
      this.$refs.popper.setSearchListIndex(index);
    }
  },
}
```

And it works.
I got Proxy like this:

```
[[Target]]: Object
  searchBar: Proxy {setPopperRelativeIndex: ƒ, onInputFocus: ƒ, onInputBlur: ƒ, onInputKeyUp: ƒ, 
  onInputKeyDown: ƒ, …}
  setSearchListIndex: ƒ ()
  show: (...)
  $: (...)
  $attrs: (...)
  $data: (...)
  $el: (...)
  $emit: (...)
  $forceUpdate: (...)
  $nextTick: (...)
  $options: (...)
  $parent: (...)
  $props: (...)
  $refs: (...)
  $root: (...)
  $router: (...)
  $slots: (...)
  $store: (...)
  $watch: (...)
  _: (...)
```

It has the function I need.

Now let's retry this, let's import component with `defineAsyncComponent()`:

```
export default {
  components: {
    SearchBarPopper: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./search-bar-popper'))
  },
};
```

Still triggred in manual event `@click`, not from `mounted()` or something.

This time I can't get that ref correctly:

```
[[Target]]: Object
  $: (...)
  $attrs: (...)
  $data: (...)
  $el: (...)
  $emit: (...)
  $forceUpdate: (...)
  $nextTick: (...)
  $options: (...)
  $parent: (...)
  $props: (...)
  $refs: (...)
  $root: (...)
  $router: (...)
  $slots: (...)
  $store: (...)
  $watch: (...)
  _: (...)
```

Ref content still printed, but inside I can't find that funciton `setSearchListIndex()`.

by the way, component `SearchBarPopper` looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="ls-view-home-search__popper">
    <ls-collapse class="ls-view-home-search__popper__wrap" :show="show">
      <search-bar-list ref="search-bar-list" />
    </ls-collapse>
  </div>
</template>
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

That is because when you define a component as async (using `defineAsyncComponent`), what you get is a wrapper component. The wrapper component is mounted as the direct child component of the parent, and it manages the async loading of your SeachBarPopper component.

If you look at the component tree in your vue devtools, you will see there is an extra `AsyncComponentWrapper` component around your true `SearchBarPopper`. Your `ref` in this case is pointing to the `AsyncComponentWrapper`, not the `SearhBarPopper` within.

Answer (score 2):

In vue 3.0.4+

they fix that problem when you bind ref to async component (using `defineAsyncComponent`).

the ref will bind to the actual component inside the `<AsyncComponentWrapper>`.

btw, if you using `<script setup>` in your custom component. you should use `defineExpose` to expose methods or other things to be used in the parent context.

```js
// child component
import { defineExpose } from 'vue'

// cannot be accessed from outside
function hello(){
    console.log('hello')
}

// can be accessed from outside cause defineExpose
function hello2(){
    console.log('hello2')
}

defineExpose({ hello2 })
```